# download file from the storage in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, storage, hosting, public

i have laravel app, and i have a problem to make a storage link in the Hostinger, i tried everything and still not working,, so now I nedd to download files directly from (storage) in my rool laravel path not in public folder, how can I do that, I tried this code:

```
 @if(is_file(storage_path('app'). '/public/user_files/files/' . $user->files))
                    <strong> <a href="{{ 'storage/app/public/user_files/files/'.$user->files }}">Download</a></strong>
```

for the code above i have accessed the files in the storage, but I couldn't download it, show me this error:

```
404 not found
```

Comment: Do you setting `storage:link` to not public folder? Look at doc https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Answer (score 0):

```
@if(is_file(storage_path('app'). '/public/storage/user_files/files/' . $user->files))
<strong> <a href="{{ asset('storage/user_files/files/'. $user->files) }}">Download</a></strong>
```

Comment: unfortunately, the same problem

Comment: Maybe you forgot add storage directory after public in your **IF** condition.

Comment: why i have to add it?, if I add it nothing will work, because the path in the if function is correct, and I can see the (download) in page, because there are files

Comment: Because storage is not located in app. look your code: **storage_path('app')**. It's wrong path. Of course you can see download link or button in your front page but it will not work until you change your path to right one.

Answer (score -1):

1st you can run this command

php artisan storage:link

you can use this path inside the assest()

```
@if(is_file(storage_path('app'). '/public/storage/user_files/files/' . $user->files))
<strong> <a href="{{ asset('storage/app/public/user_files/files/'. $user->files) }}">Download</a></strong>
```

Comment: storage:link doesn't work in the Hostinger , i have tried everything

Comment: -bash-4.2$ php artisan storage:link

   Error

  Call to undefined function Illuminate\Filesystem\symlink()

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:332
    328▕      */
    329▕     public function link($target, $link)
    330▕     {
    331▕         if (! windows_os()) {
  ➜ 332▕             return symlink($target, $link);
    333▕         }
    334▕
    335▕         $mode = $this->isDirectory($target) ? 'J' : 'H';
    336▕

      +14 vendor frames
  15  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()

Comment: you can try without if condition may be issue with your if condition
@if (!empty($user->files)) 
you can simply use this if condition